# Why doesn't "chrome.bookmarks.getTree" work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If I try the following code:

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    document.write(item.url);
  });
});
```

it returns undifined. But when I write:

```
chrome.bookmarks.getRecent(20, function(items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    document.write(item.url);
  });
});
```

it works.

Why does it differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `chrome.bookmarks.getTree` and `chrome.bookmarks.getRecent` return an array of [BookmarkTreeNodes](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html#type-BookmarkTreeNode), but BookmarkTreeNodes do not necessarily have a `url` property. In the case of `getTree`, the top nodes of the tree are folders and do not have URLs:

[image: BookmarkTreeNode structure]

If you use `getTree`, you'll have to traverse the tree recursively using each node's `children` array.  It helps to know that every BookmarkTreeNode *either* has a `children` attribute (if it's a folder) or a `url` attribute (if it's an actual bookmark).  Try something like:

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(itemTree){
    itemTree.forEach(function(item){
        processNode(item);
    });
});

function processNode(node) {
    // recursively process child nodes
    if(node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(function(child) { processNode(child); });
    }

    // print leaf nodes URLs to console
    if(node.url) { console.log(node.url); }
}
```

Comment: I think he is asking why chrome.bookmarks is not accessible, and returns undefined, I am curious too: http://i.imgur.com/b0dqJL9.png

Comment: @monstro Considering that the OP says that the second example in the question does work, you appear to have a different problem. You are welcome to post a new question for your separate issue.

Comment: have you seen the screenshot from my prev comment? Chrome console - chrome.bookmarks is undefined - why? That makes previous sample post useless, because chrome.bookmarks is undefined.

Comment: @monstro Yes, that definitely sounds like a different problem than the one addressed in this question. Feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to get help with your different problem. The OP here had difficult *using* `chrome.bookmarks` (when it was defined correctly). You are having problems getting access to `chrome.bookmarks` at all. This is different problem and should be in a different question-post.

Comment: is the above code block supposed to be in the content or background script? the api documentation is also not clear where those examples are in

Comment: @AkinHwan `chrome` APIs are not available in content scripts (except for `chrome.i18n`, `chrome.storage`, and `chrome.runtime`, according to [the docs on content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)). You will need to access `chrome.bookmarks` in your background page, and make sure you have the `"bookmarks"` permission. If you need bookmark info in your content script, you will need to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: @apsillers thank you it seems obvious now, as i was falling sleeping that was what i suspected! would i need message passing to send the return of my callback in `background.js` to my `newtab.html` newtab pageOverride (chrome_url_override)?

Comment: @apsillers or would I pass messages between my background script and content script, and then just reference the content script in my html page `<script>` tag?

Comment: @AkinHawn I'm not sure what Override Pages can and can't access but generally you'd make calls to `chrome.bookmarks` in your background page and then pass the results into your content script. (If you need more specifics, it's probably best to make a new question-post to get a better answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Before modifying your code try this!

Check if the extension has the persimo 'bookmarks'. You can see it in chrome://extensions/, 'Details' button, 'Permissions' section.

If it doesn't say 'Read and change favorites', then delete the Chrome extension and reload it unpackaged.

In my case, I loaded the extension and worked on it, updating it to incorporate the changes, then I realized that I hadn't requested the 'bookmarks' permission in the manifest.json, so I added it and updated the extension. Then chrome.bookmarks gave me 'undefined'.

It took me more than a couple of hours to realize that **the manifest.json is not updated when you update the extension, it is only updated when you delete and reupload the extension**.

D'oh!

Answer (score -2):

`chrome.bookmarks` needs permission to use. Try to use it in page 
`chrome://bookmarks`.

Comment: 1) Not relevant, since question said that `chrome.bookmarks.getRecent` works; 2) Use _what_ in that page? Chrome extensions can't access `chrome://` pages.