# How Do I Get chrome.bookmarks to Provide The Entire Tree in JSON

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

The question is succinctly this:

**How do I leverage the chrome.bookmarks API to get the JSON for the entire tree, unaltered in any way, so I can send elsewhere?**

This is for an Edge extension, for what it's worth.

The rest of this text is background so you can see I'm not just throwing this out there from nothing. Hopefully it helps you see where I've come from.

---

Looking at it on it's own, I can't find any number of methods to get it to return the JSON tree [like it says it should](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/#method-getTree):

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree()
```

Trying something like this (or any number of other attempts listed below) ... :

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(
  function(){return chrome.bookmarks.BookmarkTreeNode[0];}
)
```

... results in "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')*" ...

I am trying to code an extension (I'm still learning javascript), and I just can't get my head around the chrome.bookmarks API.

The extension has no html, and this is the manifest:

```
{
    "name": "myExtensionyWentiony",
    "description": "This is a test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "script/background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "bookmarks"
    ]
}
```

I can do the sending of a message in a number of ways using fetch(), and I can make that happen using `chrome.runtime.onStartup`. The below code (ignore anything redundant) works to simply send a command upon loading:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(
  fetch(
    'WHEREVER_IT_IS_UNIMPORTANT', 
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{"pinky": "punky", "bingo": "malingo"}'))
    }
  )
)
```

However I cannot get chrome.bookmarks to give me anything meaningful, as I only wish to take the ENTIRE JSON tree, not just part of it.

Every example I've found gives me ways to convert it into this or that, and I'm not intelligent enough to parse that for what I want. I'd just like the full JSON tree, that's it.

I've tried moving everything into distinct functions, but that doesn't help do anything. To show that I'm not just shrugging here, I've been at this all day, and within said functions, or just within the above code, from what I can remember, I have tried:

- ... using `chrome.bookmarks.getTree()` which either gives nothing
  (and stops the request from sending) or if I start to put stuff
  inside it, it gives any number of errors, the main one I can remember
  from now deleted code is "anonymous function" ... when it's *not*
  anonymous, sometimes the function *literally* has a name.
- ... using `chrome.bookmarks.getTree([0])` which on its own returns a promise to the browser, but when used to try to send data to somewhere else, it does nothing.
- ... `chrome.bookmarks.getTree(tree)`, which gives no result, and
  doesn't fire the request.
- ... putting functions inside the getTree, and the same results come
  through, either nothing, or anonymous function.
- ... using `chrome.bookmarks.getChildren()` either on it's own with a
  '`0`' in there to represent the root of the tree, or with nothing. Same errors.
- ... the previous attempt inside the getTree on its own, or inside a
  function and referenced by the getTree.
- ... placing getTree or getChildren as constants, variables, and variations upon using or referencing functions within those.
- ... using `chrome.bookmarks.getSubTree(0)` (or any number) results in "No matching signature" and an "anonymous function" error. This is either on its own, or inside a getTree.
- ... searching for "chrome.bookmarks" "anonymous function" with nothing I could find being of use.

I'm really at a loss, if anyone knows which command I need to use here to send the full JSON tree (which from the docs I'd have through getTree does) then I'd be eternally grateful for any assistance that you could provide. I'm assuming this is revolving around Promises, but they're really difficult to make work as far as I can see.

If it could be kept as simple as possible, too, that'd be great. I don't see how it should need to be complicated, mind.

Not expecting any responses, but if you can it would be great.

---

Have also looked at:

- [Why doesn't "chrome.bookmarks.getTree" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268776/why-doesnt-chrome-bookmarks-gettree-work/10292336#10292336)
- [How do I use promises in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844405/how-do-i-use-promises-in-a-chrome-extension)

---

**EDIT - Progress**
Some progress, using [Mozilla/FireFox code from their docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/get), has at least got the console showing the full bookmarks, which is way more than has been achieved up until now.

```
function onFulfilled(bookmarks) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
};

function onRejected(error) {
  console.log(`An error: ${error}`);
};

let gettingBookmarks = chrome.bookmarks.getTree([0]);
let binky = gettingBookmarks.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

However if I place try to call binky in the body of the fetch, it doesn't fire the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the answer using the [Mozilla/FireFox code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/get) (I'll edit that link into the question) to move it around about to do this.

Mozilla had the only page that I could understand which made some sense of the promise handling.

So using their example I got the Edge bookmarks array using this:

```
function onFulfilled(bookmarks) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  fetch(
    'WHEREVER_IT_IS_UNIMPORTANT', 
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bookmarks)
    }
  )
};

function onRejected(error) {
  console.log(`An error: ${error}`);
};


  let gettingBookmarks = chrome.bookmarks.getTree([0]);
  gettingBookmarks.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

Slightly annoyed that I didn't make the question about sending this on `chrome.runtime.onStartup`, but I sense getting it in there will be much easier. (but welcome the comments!).

As is, this technically answers the question how do I get the full JSON tree to use elsewhere.